# PHP in_array results always same.

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
    $a = $monitoring->getMonitoringServers();
    if (in_array("192.168.100.253", $a))
        echo "y";
    else
        echo "n";
?>
```

`print_r($a)` yields:

```
Array (
   [0] => stdClass Object ( [address] => 192.168.100.253 )
   [1] => stdClass Object ( [address] => 192.168.100.253 )
)
```

What's wrong with this code? The answer is always no!

Comment: Please improve the question title. It doesn't really say anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is made of objects, not strings.

By doing `in_array("192.168.100.253", $a)` you are looking for the string `"192.168.100.253"` inside $a, and as you can see on the print_r - it's inside an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$flag = false;
foreach($a as $obj){
  if($obj->address == "192.168.100.253"){
     $flag = true;
     break;
  }
}

if($flag){
   echo 'Y';
}
else{
   echo 'N';
}
```

$a is array of stdObjects, and you are treating them as normal values.

You are required to use a foreach loop to iterate through each element of $a.

Answer (score 0):

The `$a` var is an object, not an array.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#103983 for a function that also works on objects.

Comment: No, it's an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

its simple try dis

> $a = $monitoring->getMonitoringServers();
>
> if (!in_array("192.168.100.253", $a->address )
>      echo "y"; else   echo "n"; ?>
>   u l get output as n